# How to create Google calendar through auth api and share it for multiple user for edit and view in php

Tags: javascript, php, google-calendar-api

I tried more but i did not find the exact doc plz share any idea to implement google calendar dynamically and that can be share to user for edit and view.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php#prerequisites) guide in [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) documentation. It provides steps on how to integrate a simple PHP command-line application that makes requests to the Google Calendar API. This might help.

You can view the calendar by calling the [calendarList.get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get) method. It returns an entry on the user's calendar list. See the [example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/get#examples):

```
$calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->get('calendarId');

echo $calendarListEntry->getSummary();
```

Then you can Edit/Update an entry on the user's calendar list by calling [calendarList:update](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/update) method. [Example](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendarList/update#examples):

```
$updatedCalendarListEntry = service->calendarList->update($calendarListEntry->getId(), $calendarListEntry);

echo $updatedCalendarListEntry->getEtag();
```

Check the GitHub examples below:

- https://github.com/montania/Google-Calendar-API-PHP-Class
- https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Calendar.php

Comment: thanks for your answer ! i also need to create calendar dynamically based on some parameter like calendar name,date time .please help me

Comment: You can see [here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/settings) the setting resources that users can change from the Calendar UI, such as the user's time zone. They can be retrieved via list and get methods. Note that if a setting has its default value, it might not be returned.

Comment: You should also use [Service Account](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/service-accounts) if you want a server-server interaction between a web application and a Google service. Example, if your app wants to add events to the calendars of all users in a Google Apps domain, then you need to use a service account to access the Google Calendar API on behalf of users.